# How to iterate easily over interface properties

Tags: typescript

Is there the possibility of iterating over an interface properties in an elegant way and return a result based on a certain logic.  I have an interface and I want to read the properties values to see if the values are empty or not and based on that I determine a final result.

Interface is :

```
 errors: {
    confirmPassword: "",
    email: "",
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    password: ""
  }
```

Now, I want to iterate through the properties and if anyone of them has some value, I return a true or false if all of them are empty.

Comment: Loop through `Object.values(<object>)` of an object which implements the interface?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Array/every)

```js
let errors =  {
    confirmPassword: "",
    email: "",
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    password: ""
};

let result = Object.values(errors).every(v => v == "");
console.log(result);
```

Or you can simply use a for loop for the same.

```js
let errors = {
  confirmPassword: "",
  email: "",
  firstname: "",
  lastname: "",
  password: ""
};

let result = true;
for (let key in errors) {
  if(errors[key] != "") {
    result = false;
    break;
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I am using typescript and I am having the error[ts] Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. [2339]

Comment: @jupitersailormoon - I have updated answer with a simple for loop. I hope that works with typescript. You will just need to update l`et result` to `let result <boolean>`

Comment: He's talking about interfaces, not objects or classes. This will not work.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets - In general coding practices, people tend to call the communicator object/layer as interface. I believe OP has accepted the answer, hence, assuming the answer addresses the problem.

Comment: The OP has indeed accepted the answer, but I don't know why and as I'm facing the same question, I'd like to point out that this doesn't work. Furthermore, the question is tagged with `TypeScript` so I think it's clear that we're not talking about general "communicator object/layers", but TypeScript interfaces. The correct answer, for anyone who stumbles into this before reading other similar questions, is that it's simply not possible with TypeScript at the moment. You have to either use classes, or instantiate an object with all the interface properties (to use your solution).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Array method .some()

```js
let errors= {
confirmPassword: "",
email: "",
firstname: "",
lastname: "",
password: ""
  };
let allNull = Object.keys(errors).some(function(k) {
    return errors[k] === "";
});
console.log(allNull);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot iterate over interface properties as the interface doesn't exists in runtime.

You can iterate over object properties with obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)

```
var buz = {
    fog: 'stack'
};

for (var name in buz) {
    if (buz.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        alert("this is fog (" + name + ") for sure. Value: " + buz[name]);
    }
    else {
        alert(name); // toString or something else
    }
}
```