# How to iterate over Typescript interface properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have an interface `FilterData`, which looks like the following:

```
export interface FilterData {
  variables?: string[];
  processDefinitionKey?: string;
}
```

In a request to the server, I receive the object `filterSettings` which is of a type `FilterData`, and I need to iterate over it.

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
for (const key in filterSettings) {
  filterString += `${key}_eq_${filterSettings[key]},`;
}
```

But I receive the following error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
>   'string' can't be used to index type 'FilterData'.   No index
>   signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type
>   'FilterData'.ts(7053)

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54664361/how-to-iterate-easily-over-interface-properties) that the interface doesn't exist on the runtime, but I have no idea about what workaround could be. How I can iterate over the interface object?

Comment: Can you please share your entire code? I don't think there's any problem with the code you posted here. `const key in filterSettings`, at runtime, does not use `FilterData` but just the object properties of `filterSettings`. It should work (and does in my little scratch file).

Comment: i tried.. i didnt get error. did u try to update typescript ?

Comment: @xdeepakv You do get that error if your typescript config does not allow implicit any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just say to typescript that you're sure that `key` is `keyof Filterdata` :

```
for (const key in filterSettings) {
  filterString += `${key}_eq_${filterSettings[key as keyof FilterData]},`;
}
```

You can either set `noImplicitAny: false` in your `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 1):

It is true that interfaces dont exist at runtime, but you can still iterate over properties of an existing object from that interface.

Please see my answer here [How to loop though Record<K, T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205772/how-to-loop-though-recordk-t/61206618#61206618) for ways to iterate through an object

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the interface doesn't exist at runtime. You have to hardcode the properties that you want - the object that implements the interface might have any other properties as well:

```
const filterSettings: FilterData;

for (const key of ['variables', 'processDefinitionKey']) {
  filterString += `${key}_eq_${filterSettings[key]},`;
}
```